# How can I read formatted data in C?

Tags: c

In `data.txt`

```
jeju islan, 15:00, 16:00
```

In test.c

```
char* a;
char* b;
char* c;
scanf("%[^,], %s, %s", a, b, c);
```

and

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test <data.txt
```

but the result is

```
Segmentation fault :11
```

I want to know what's my fault.

Comment: You haven't allocated space for the strings to be read into; you're using uninitialized pointers.  On Linux (POSIX 2008-compliant systems), consider `scanf("%m[^,], %m[^,], %s", &a, &b, &c)`; otherwise, allocate the space for the values to be read into and then use a modified version of your format, with `%[^,]` for the second string too.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost the correct format<sup>*</sup>. The most common reason to get a segfault in this situation is that `tmp.name`, `tmp.open`, or `tmp.close` does not have enough space to store the value, or you pass uninitialized pointers.

Make sure that all three fields are either arrays or pointers that have been properly `malloc`-ed:

```
char* a = malloc(100);
char* b = malloc(10);
char* c = malloc(10);
int count = scanf("%99[^,], %9[^,], %9s", a, b, c);
if (count == 3) { // All three items were read successfully
    ... // Do something with a, b, and c
}
free(a);
free(b);
free(c);
```

<sup>*</sup> Thanks, Jonathan Leffler, for the correction!

Comment: No; it is not the correct format.  The second format needs to be a `%[^,]` scan set; the `%s` will read the comma, and then the matching will fail, assigning nothing to the third string.

Comment: Question. When %99%[^,] is done, where is comma gone in the text? I mean the comma right after jeju islan in the data.txt

Comment: Thank you so much, I learned a lot !!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should provide arguments to `scanf` as pointers - try this:

```
scanf("%[^,], %s, %s", &tmp.name, &tmp.open, &tmp.close);
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you're right - in my answer it should be formatted as `%as`, in this case `scanf` would allocate memory automatically.

Comment: Well, and it seems that `%as` has been deprecated as well. So yeah, `malloc` would be the right solution here.

Comment: `%as` is a GNU C Library extension that's deprecated in favour of the `%ms` POSIX 2008 standard notation (see [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)).  It is available on Linux and Mac OS X (BSD).